# What’s the correct usage of “modulo”?

Tags: grammaticality, mathematics, syntactic-analysis

How would we rephrase the following sentence to be grammatical? :

> 10 **modulo** 3 equals 1.

By "grammatical", I probably mean something along the lines of *standard American English*.

Initially, I'd thought that its grammatical, but dictionary.com [claims that *modulo* is an adverb](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/modulo) and not a verb, so it seems that the above usage is wrong.

What’s the standard and accepted usage of the word *modulo*?

Comment: The classical usage would be $10$ equals $3$ modulo $1$,

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Modulo can be preposition or an adjective. It is neither a verb nor an adverb.

Comment: @tchrist  the source I provided in the question (dictionary.com) states that it is an adverb..

Comment: [AHED](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=modulo), [Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/modulo), [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/modulo?region=us&q=modulo), and [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/modulo) all list _modulo_ as a preposition. Dictionary.com is in a distinct minority, and I wouldn't worry about phrasing something grammatically based on its possibly erroneous categorization.

Comment: If you want the mathematical sentence translated, it means "10 divided by 3 leaves 1 as a remainder". As I suspect you already know. The prepositional use of _modulo_ outside that context is much more fraught; it's a vague nod to certain boundary conditions, and it can be **way** overdone, especially in Biz Biz.

Comment: Modulo is the name of a math operator.  If "Two plus three equals five" is grammatical, so is 10 modulo 3 equals 1.

Comment: @Oldcat The cool kids all call it 'mod'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mathematics would say: "10 is congruent to 1 modulo 3".  The modified usage "10 modulo 3" with "modulo" as an operation (like "10 plus 3") is from computer programming.

Comment: No, modulo as a preposition is older than computer programming is.  Check the OED for [mod](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/120566), [modulo](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/120692). These are from the 19ᵗʰ century (barely): the first documented use appears to be Gauss in 1801.

Comment: Yes, what I wrote is correct.  It does not contradict "modulo as a preposition".

Answer (score 4):

The verb in your sentence is *equals*. The entire sentence can be parsed either as *10 modulo 3* being a noun phrase with *modulo 3* operating as an adjective, or as *modulo 3 equals* being a verb phrase with *modulo 3* operating as an adverb. Whichever analysis is preferred, the usage is perfectly standard, if slightly imprecise. The reference you cite is correct to prefer *is congruent to* over *equals*.

Comment: 10 is a noun right? so 10 modulo 3 = [noun][adverb][noun] and that's a grammatical phrase?

Comment: @Pacerier  Binary operators like 4+5 or 10%3 are grammatically prepositions.  Four *plus* five, ten *modulo* three.

Answer (score 1):

In a non-searchable and potentially ephemeral comment to the original posting, Professor Lawler kindly presented the following answer:

> If you want the mathematical sentence translated, it means “10 divided by 3 leaves 1 as a remainder”. As I suspect you already know.
>
> The prepositional use of *modulo* outside that context is much more fraught; it’s a vague nod to certain boundary conditions, and it can be **way** overdone, especially in Biz Biz.

I’ve marked this posting Community Wiki because it is John’s answer not my own, and so I deserve no reputation from it.

Answer (score 0):

The most syntactically sound way I can say "10 modulo 3 equals 1" is

```
(10 % 3) == 1
```

That holds in a great many languages, but not spoken English. I do hear it spoken often enough as a computer scientist, though, and when it's not simply, "ten mod three," it's "ten modulo three," and occasionally "ten modulus three." There are other ways you could phrase it, but these are all that I have heard spoken, and this from the lips of exceedingly well educated computer science profs.

Modulus comes from Latin; [it means "little measure."](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/definition/27113/modulus-moduli) "Modulus" uses the the *nominative* ending, which is for subjects. "Modulo" uses the *ablative* ending, so you can translate as "from the little measure," "with the little measure," "by the little measure," or "in the little measure," among other possibilities depending on the context. In English, "[modulo](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/modulo)" simply becomes a preposition, like "[plus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plus)." You could say, "the modulus of ten with respect to three," or, "ten modulo three," but "ten modulus three" is pretty shaky. The operator "%" I have seen called both a "modulus operator" and a "modulo operator," but my texts all say "modulus operator."