# The meaning of "modulo"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meaning of “modulo the fact”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70018/meaning-of-modulo-the-fact)

I just saw a construction quoted below.

> Every answer that wasn't this particular user's had been downvoted (modulo one that was a one-liner summary of his answer).

To my understanding, "modulo" is a mathematical operator, roughly put for computing the rest term in a division. What does it do in this sentence?

Comment: Not merely exact duplicate, but also general reference.

Answer (score 0):

The term "*a* modulo *b*" in a mathematical setting means that anything equal to *b* in *a* is disregarded (more specifically, set to zero).

Here it means that the answer that was a one-liner had not been downvoted, while every other answer one had been downvoted.